# How do you combine two sum queries into one?

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT dep.depName, SUM(worker.salary) as total
FROM team, worker
WHERE worker.depID = dep.depID
GROUP BY dep.depID

SELECT dep.depName, SUM(manager.salary) as total
FROM manager, dep
WHERE manager.depID = dep.depID
GROUP BY team.depID
```

I tried something along the line of: SELECT dep.depName, SUM(manager.salary)+SUM(worker.salary) as total but it gave me some strange output, it adds N elements N number of time.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Explain what result you expect to get after that.

Comment: both sum queries work as they should, but not when i "combine" them, that is i do sum(a+b). i expect the correct sum.

Comment: that's why I asked what do you mean by "combine".

Comment: " i expect the correct sum" --- you are grouping by different columns, not sure how it's possible to sum values with different units

Comment: There is some "bug" in both queries...in the first one, there is no dep table defined, and you are grouping on a field that is not in the SELECT  In the second query, you are also grouping on a field that is not in the SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more efficient way is to sum the results by department *without* doing a join.  Then join in the department name.

This method also allows you to separate the department salaries into the two groups:

```
select depId, sum(wsalary) as wsalary, sum(msalary) as msalary,
       sum(wsalary) + sum(msalary) as total
from ((select depId, sum(w.salary) as wsalary, null as msalary
       from worker w
       group by depId
      )
      union all
      (select depId, NULL as wsalary, sum(m.salary) as msalary
       from manager m
       group by depId
      )
     ) t join
     dep d
     on t.depId = d.depId
group by t.depId
```

I am assuming the `team` in the first `from` clause really refers to `dep`, as used in the rest of the query.

Comment: "The more efficient way is to sum the results by department without doing a join. Then join in the department name." --- it's tricky to predict that without execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a subquery of a UNION statement

```
SELECT dep.depName, sum(salary) as total, dep.depID 
FROM
(
    (SELECT dep.depName, worker.salary as salary, dep.depID
        FROM team, worker
        WHERE worker.depID = dep.depID
    ) 
    UNION 
   (SELECT dep.depName, manager.salary as salary, dep.depID
       FROM manager, dep
       WHERE manager.depID = dep.depID
   )
) dep GROUP BY dep.depID
```

Comment: He grouped by dep.depID in his example code. (The team table wasn't even defined in the second sample query).

Comment: "The team table wasn't even defined in the second sample query" --- oh, that makes sense

Comment: Next: you have a cartesian product of `manager x dep`. IE: if for particular `dep.depID` first query returned 3 rows and for the second 3 rows as well - your query will return 9 rows

Comment: @dethtron5000: I would remove nested aggregations. They bring nothing to the result but make the query less readable and hardly maintainable

Comment: Now +1 :-) PS: excuse me for making a minor fix for your answer (otherwise it would throw "every derived table should have alias" error)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this :

```
SELECT result.depName, SUM(worker.salary) as total, manager_total
FROM team, worker
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT dep.depID as depID, dep.depName as depName, SUM(manager.salary) as manager_total
    FROM dep
    LEFT OUTER JOIN manager ON manager.depID = dep.depID
    GROUP BY dep.depID, dep.depName) as result ON result.depID = team.depID
WHERE worker.depID = team.depID
GROUP BY result.depName, manager_total
```

Comment: @zerkms In the question, this is not take in consideration since there is no OUTER JOIN. I will wait a comment by the OP to edit my answer

Comment: in the question OP wanted to summarize the values. The first OPs query would return `N`, the second - nothing. `N` + nothing == `N`. Your query would return nothing. Mismatch.

Comment: can i set a condition for each sum?